# Magento 2 : hide sidebar on mobile view

Tags: magento2, blocks, mobile, magento2.2.3, containers

- Magento 2.2.3
- Theme: Luma

My homepage uses layout: 2 column with left bar. I want to hide the image block ( CMS static block ) or whole sidebar container `referenceContainer name="sidebar.main"` from home page when the page enters mobile mode ( *width < 768px* ). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want layout changes only in mobile.

So best way to use CSS/LESS to achieve your output

To hide **sidebar-main section** in mobile below **768px** add below css in you css/less file.

```
.cms-index-index .columns .sidebar-main {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide **additional sidebar section** as well in mobile then use below css instead of top one.

```
.cms-index-index .columns .sidebar-main,
.cms-index-index .columns .sidebar-additional {
    display: none;
}
```

If you aware of LESS then in your theme go to

> ..\app\design\frontend[VENDOR][THEME]\Magento_Theme\web\css\source_module.less

find media

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {

'''

}
```

so add above give css  at the end of close tag

as per your need (only sidebar-main css or both).

**Note :** Magento default **@screen__m**  variable value is **768px**

whole less syntex represent mobile media till 767px
or
means  **@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)**

after adding these changes you might not get your changes so do static content deploy

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**Note :** `-f`  will help to deploy even in deloper mode